# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test (default-test) on project spring-petclinic: There are test failures

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I'm working on test automation project to integrate SonarQube Analysis with Azure pipelines using Java and Maven task. every time the pipeline is triggered the build is failed encountered with the following error and when uncheck the Code Analysis -> Run SonarQube or SonarCloud Analysis under maven task the build is successfull

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test (default-test) on project spring-petclinic: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/vsts/work/1/s/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I tried changing different versions of **org.apache.maven.plugins** with no luck, as well as tried switching between **Java versions** 11, 17, and 21, but the Maven plugin error persists.

> POM.xml file

```
<!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-io-platform.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-io-platform.version>
        <spring-data-jdbc.version>1.1.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jdbc.version>


        <!-- Java EE / Java SE dependencies -->
        <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <assertj.version>2.2.0</assertj.version>

        <!-- Dates -->
        <jodatime-hibernate.version>1.3</jodatime-hibernate.version>
        <jodatime-jsptags.version>1.1.1</jodatime-jsptags.version>
        <jadira-usertype-core.version>3.2.0.GA</jadira-usertype-core.version>

        <!-- Others -->
        <mysql-driver.version>5.1.36</mysql-driver.version>

        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <dandelion.version>1.1.1</dandelion.version>
        <dandelion.datatables.version>1.1.0</dandelion.datatables.version>

        <cobertura.version>2.7</cobertura.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <!-- Import the maven Spring IO Platform Bill Of Materials (BOM) -->
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-io-platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>${jadira-usertype-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-jstlel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  JSon -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPRING, SPRING, SPRINGITY SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jdbc.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!--  because Spring Data usually comes with a slightly older version of Spring -->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- used for EhCacheCacheManager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database connection pool
        See here for more details on commons-dbcp versus tomcat-jdbc:
        http://blog.ippon.fr/2013/03/13/improving-the-performance-of-the-spring-petclinic-sample-application-part-3-of-5/
    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Date and Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${jodatime-hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
            <version>${jodatime-jsptags.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Databases - Uses HSQL by default -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For MySql only -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency-->

        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dandelion -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>dandelion-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-export-itext</artifactId>
            <version>${dandelion.datatables.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- temporary fix: below dependency should not be necessary as it is a transitive dependency.
        For some reason we can't build the app unless it is a first level dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Maven plugin versions are mentioned in order to guarantee the build reproducibility in the long term -->
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <!-- declared explicitly so Spring config files can be placed next to their corresponding JUnit test class  -->
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <Xlint/>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>petclinic</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.*</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
                    <port>9966</port>
                    <path>/petclinic</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <check/>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>

            <!--  integrate maven-cobertura-plugin to project site  -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                    </formats>
                    <check/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>bower-install</id>
            <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>bower</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
          </build>
        </profile>
   </profiles>
```

Comment: You know that the spring platform end of life since 2019 !!  https://spring.io/projects/platform#overview Apart from that the whole POM contains ancient old versions of deps etc. also using JODA Time for JDK8+ project does not make sense...Changing the default layout does not really make sense using ancient old version of maven-surefire-plugin/maven-war-plugin/  Maven Eclipse Plugin is retired since 2015!!  (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) Cobertura? I would get rid of it... because I doubt that it works correctly for JDK8

Comment: You have an ancient old setup which you try to build with JDK11+ that will not work because all deps, plugins etc. ancient old also the old framework (I doubt that it even will work in JDK9+ etc)..

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with the following tings:

1. Ensure you have installed the extension [**SonarQube**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) to your Azure DevOps organization.
2. Before the Maven task, ensure you have added a **Prepare Analysis Configuration** task from the **SonarQube** extension. This configuration task need you set up a **SonarQube Server Endpoint** to connect to your SonarQube Server.
3. The **`install`** or **`package`** goal should run first before starting the SonarQube Analysis.

   [image]
4. If you have specified the version of the SonarQube Maven plugin in your project POM file and want to use the specified version, you can select the option "**`Use version declared in your pom.xml`**".

   [image]

---